# Función de carrusel mediante CSS y Javascript (mejorar función)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Bueno primero que nada me gustaría aclarar que no es un carrusel como tal solo que no se como nombrarlo, lo que estoy tratando ahora es mejorar el script que ya tengo pero no se si se puede hacer algo como tal o si exista un plugin que haga esto de manera mas sencilla. pero el punto es que hice esto de esta manera por que el nivel de acceso que tengo para editar el html es limitado por temas de servicios de terceros, en fin lo que hago es juntar todos mis elementos artículos el un div padre con el **id **grupo-1**** al 5 y dentro de estos div padres hay unos div hijos con el **id col-1** al 10 y dentro de cada hijo metí un elemento article (*con el fin de separarlos y tener un orden y usar clases de Bootstrap para pasar al diseño responsivo*) esto lo hago mediante JavaScript.

este es el script que uso para hacer lo anteriormente mencionado:

```
    const noticiasContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.noticias');
    let uniqueGroupCounter = 1;

    noticiasContainers.forEach(noticiasContainer => {
    const articulos = noticiasContainer.querySelectorAll('article');
    const artículosPorGrupo = 10;

    for (let i = 0; i < articulos.length; i += artículosPorGrupo) {
        const grupoDiv = document.createElement('div');
        grupoDiv.className = 'grupo-noticias row align-items-center';
        grupoDiv.id = `grupo-${uniqueGroupCounter}`;

        for (let j = i; j < i + artículosPorGrupo && j < articulos.length; j++) {
        const article = articulos[j];

        const colDiv = document.createElement('div');
        colDiv.className = 'col-sm';
        colDiv.appendChild(article);

        // Agrega un ID único al colDiv
        colDiv.id = `col-${j + 1}`;

        grupoDiv.appendChild(colDiv);
        }

        noticiasContainer.appendChild(grupoDiv);
        uniqueGroupCounter++;
    }
    });
```

y termino teniendo algo así pero de estos obtengo 4 (50 artículos en total) mas solo por temas prácticos solo expondré el primero:

```
<div id="grupo-1">

    <div id="col-1">
        <article></article>
    </div>

    <div id="col-2">
        <article></article>
    </div>

    . . . 

    <div id="col-10">
        <article></article>
    </div>

</div>
```

bien ahora lo que hice fue que con css anteriormente oculte los elementos 5 al 10 con un display none. ¿por que los últimos 5 elementos? bien pues son los que cabían en mi monitor y no pensé en el diseño responsivo hasta después (cosa que quiero resolver).

```
.grupo-noticias div:nth-child(n+6) {
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

ahora que saben esto paso a explicar como es que estoy ocultando ahora los elementos, básicamente primero identifico el div padre le creo unos botones con dom para hacer la función de avanzar y retroceder declaró unas variables de artículos que me van ayudar a resolver que artículos debo modificar y así saber cuando avanza y ando retroceder pero eso solo es un efecto ya que lo que hago en realidad es ocular y mostrar el elemento:

```
    //busco el elemnto del grupo de noticas para usarlo despues en la creacion de botones
    const contenedor = document.querySelector("#grupo-1");

    // declaro los botnoes a usar dentro del grupo de articulos 
    const retrocederButton = document.createElement("button");
    retrocederButton.textContent = "Retroceder";
    retrocederButton.setAttribute("class", "buttonR1");
    contenedor.appendChild(retrocederButton);

    const avanzarButton = document.createElement("button");
    avanzarButton.textContent = "Avanzar";
    avanzarButton.setAttribute("class", "buttonA1");
    contenedor.appendChild(avanzarButton);

    //escucho el evento click de los botones y ejecuto las funciones respectivas
    retrocederButton.addEventListener("click", retroceder);
    avanzarButton.addEventListener("click", avanzar);

    // Constantes de los articulos que hay que actualizar 
    let articuloA = 1;
    let articuloB = 6;
    
    function avanzar() {
    if (articuloA <= 5) {
        document.querySelector(`#grupo-1 div.col-sm:nth-child(${articuloA})`).style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector(`#grupo-1 div.col-sm:nth-child(${articuloB})`).style.position = 'relative';
        document.querySelector(`#grupo-1 div.col-sm:nth-child(${articuloB})`).style.display = 'inline';
        articuloA++;
        articuloB++;
    }
    }

    function retroceder() {
        if (articuloA > 1) {
            articuloA--;
            articuloB--;
            document.querySelector(`#grupo-1 div.col-sm:nth-child(${articuloA})`).style.display = 'block';
            document.querySelector(`#grupo-1 div.col-sm:nth-child(${articuloB})`).style.position = 'absolute';
            document.querySelector(`#grupo-1 div.col-sm:nth-child(${articuloB})`).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

ahora bien funciona pero no como quisiera ya que necesito que se adapte a las diversas pantallas, lo cual puedo resolver con css. **¿pero para mantener la función como podría hacerlo?**, ya que en movil espero mostrar el primer div (*y ocultar los demás pero solo oculto los 5 últimos y los 5 primeros se ven*), hacer mi función de ocultar el primer div y mostrar el segundo , así sucesivamente hasta llegar al div 10 (*ya que solo mostraria de uno en uno en el diseño movil,no tiene por que ser un bucle infinito con el botón de avanzar y retroceder*), en las demás pantallas mostrar los div necesarios para abarcar el ancho de la pantalla ya sea mostrar 3 div y ocultar los demás e ir mostrándolos y ocultándolos de acuerdo al botón, pensaba en alguna forma de contar cuantos elementos dentro de mi div padre son de estilo display none una vez que los identifico pasar a ocultar el primer elemento de la lista que no tenga el estilo display none y dar el estilo display inline al primer elemento que tenga display none que no sea al que se acaba de otorgar el estilo, un poco confuso talvez pero fue lo que se me ocurrió.

en resumen mi script solo esta preparado para esperar los 5 últimos elementos ocultos y mostrarlos, ocultando los otros primeros 5, quiero hacer uso de media query de css para dar el display none a los elementos que no caben en el ancho de mi pantalla (de esta manera resolvería el diseño responsivo, creo) pero ni script no espera esto ¿alguna forma de resolverlo, herramienta o plugin que sugieran?

sus comentarios serian de mucha ayuda gracias.

Comment: A ver si entiendo, tienes un carrousel que muestra de 5 en 5 y para móvil quieres mostrar de 1 en 1, es eso?

Comment: si en pocas palabras